# Can we have Continuous integration and delivery on Databricks using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks

My requirement is to take automatic back up of Databricks Notebooks at scheduled time intervals and push it to Azure DevOps Repository. I need to fetch from around 10 Databricks workspaces and push it to a single Azure DevOps Repository. Is there any methods available to achieve the same ! Also, while going through Databricks Support Docs, I came across the below mentioned material. Can one script be used for taking backup of Multiple Workspaces in to Azure DevOps Repos !

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/ci-cd.html

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you can try to link the workbook with the repository and commit into the repository directly with the following steps:

1.Open your notebook, notice **Revision history** on the right top section of the screen. Click on **Revision history** to bring up the version history side panel.

2.Click on `Git: Not Linked` to update `Git Preferences`. Link your workbook to Azure DevOps Repo, which should be the URL of your git repository, and set the Path in Git Repo to the location which you want Databricks to save your notebook inside the repository.

[image]

[image]

For details ,please refer to the Step3 part of this [document](https://medium.com/@bedatse/azure-devops-ci-cd-with-azure-databricks-and-data-factory-part-1-c05a44536a8e). In addition, I think the [script](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/ci-cd.html#develop-and-commit-your-code) in the link you mentioned is also feasible,you can also try it.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. But in this case, we have to manually link notebooks individually. But in my case, I need to periodically backup all the notebooks inside a folder to Azure Repos using a single script/ or any unified solution.

Comment: If so, the ideal solution is to first use the rest api to get all the notebooks in the folder, and then push these notebooks to the azure repo through the git command, but I am not familiar with databricks, so I am not sure if there is such a rest api.